# Proper nuclear reaction notation for arbitrary species

Tags: nuclear-physics, notation

I am wondering the common way to write a nuclear reaction for an arbitrary species.  For instance, for neutron capture on a species $X$:

$$^{A}_ZX + n \rightarrow ^{A+1}_{\ \ \ \ \ Z}X'.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: First of all it is fully correct, second, I am trying to get a better notation - but I don't know whether I'll succeed.

Comment: are you pleased? If yes, get into the text of your question with *edit*, and you will see what I did.

Comment: I am pleased, yes

Comment: Very well. Though, to my taste, it were more aesthetical to write $^{A+1}_{\ \ \ Z}X'.$

Comment: On a barely related note, when using real $\LaTeX$, the isotope package automates the markup complexities for you.